# can not able to load dojo.js

Tags: javascript, dojo

As I am trying my hands on [dojotoolkit](https://dojotoolkit.org), I try to run (open) following html code in my browser, as they said on tutorial, but my browser does not able to load **dojo.js**

At time of troubleshooting I found that source URL is converted like following:

**file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>

    <script>
        require([
            'dojo/dom',
            'dojo/dom-construct'
        ], function (dom, domConstruct) {
            var greetingNode = dom.byId('greeting');
            domConstruct.place('<em> Dojo!</em>', greetingNode);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried changing `src="//ajax.googleapis..."` to `src="http://ajax.googleapis...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a real webserver, rather than browsing from the filesystem.

While Frank is correct in that adding an explicit protocol to the URL will fix this particular issue, you are inevitably going to run into other issues anyway, such as XHR being locked down from the `file://` protocol.  The protocol-relative URL you were originally using will work fine if you test on a real webserver which serves http or https.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add **http** as the protocol for the **dojo.js** file source.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
```

Also best practice is to add library files in the **head** tag instead of the **body** tag.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>

    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Scripts at the end of body is a common best practice since older browsers especially limit the number of concurrent script downloads which can slow the loading of other resources (styles, images, etc.) that could otherwise be loaded more in parallel first.  Meanwhile, normally, `src="//..."` is a protocol-relative URL, so it will load `http` if the web page being viewed is `http`, or `https` if it's `https`, which is fine, but if `file://` is being used in this case, that's the *real* problem and will cause other problems even when this is fixed.

Comment: Like @KenFranqueiro said, scripts are pretty commonly put at the bottom of the page, even libraries. AFAIK there are certain browsers that have a limit of only downloading 2 resources from the same host simultaneous. Read more here: https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom